# Finding an array's objects that are not present in another array by property

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, underscore.js

I'm looking for a way to find any objects in one array that are not present in another array based upon that object's **property**. What's the best way to do this with jQuery or underscore?

Given the following example:

```
"array1":[
    {"testProperty":"A"}, 
    {"testProperty":"B"}, 
    {"testProperty":"C"}
]

"array2":[
    {"testProperty":"A", "User":"Smith"}, 
    {"testProperty":"B", "User":"Smith"}, 

]
```

I would want to return the third object from array1 whose **testProperty** is "C" since it's not present in array2.

I was able to find several examples of this issue here on stackoverflow, but not when needing to do so using properties from those objects.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this counts, but if you can use lodash instead of underscore, there is a nice function called differenceBy:

```
var _ = require("lodash");

var array1 = [
  {"testProperty":"A"},
  {"testProperty":"B"},
  {"testProperty":"C"}
]

var array2 = [
  {"testProperty":"A", "User":"Smith"},
  {"testProperty":"B", "User":"Smith"}
]

var result = _.differenceBy(array1, array2, function(item) {
  return item["testProperty"]
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

A proposal in plain Javascript with a hash table for look-up.

```js
var data = { "array1": [{ "testProperty": "A" }, { "testProperty": "B" }, { "testProperty": "C" }], "array2": [{ "testProperty": "A", "User": "Smith" }, { "testProperty": "B", "User": "Smith" }, ] },
    result = data.array1.filter(function (a) {
        return !this[a.testProperty];
    }, data.array2.reduce(function (r, a) {
        r[a.testProperty] = true;
        return r;
    }, Object.create(null)));

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: I prefer the jQuery approach but this works great, thanks!

Comment: @Haymak3r jQuery approach? what does that even mean? none of these answers require jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filter` with `map`

```js
var a = {'array1': [{"testProperty":"A"}, {"testProperty":"B"}, {"testProperty":"C"}], 'array2': [{"testProperty":"A", "User":"Smith"}, {"testProperty":"B", "User":"Smith"}]};

var result = a.array1.filter(function(e) {
  return a.array2.map(el => { return el.testProperty}).indexOf(e.testProperty) == -1;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is incredibly inefficient. You map over all of `array2` on each iteration of `filter`, which is totally unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

here's a version in plain es6 js using filter and some method:

```js
array1 = [
    {"testProperty":"A"}, 
    {"testProperty":"B"}, 
    {"testProperty":"C"}
];

array2 =[
    {"testProperty":"A", "User":"Smith"}, 
    {"testProperty":"B", "User":"Smith"}, 

]
  
 var r = array1.filter(x =>
    ! Object.keys(x).some(z =>
      array2.some(w =>
      Object.keys(w).some(y => y === z && w[y] === x[z])
    )));
    
    document.write(JSON.stringify(r))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use underscore's [**reject**](http://underscorejs.org/#reject) and [**some**](http://underscorejs.org/#some) to get what you want:

```
var result = _.reject(array1, item => _.some(array2, {testProperty: item.testProperty}));
```

If performance is a concern and testProperty is an unique key of the objects in array2 then you could create a hash using [**indexBy**](http://underscorejs.org/#indexBy) and check for the result using [**has**](http://underscorejs.org/#has):

```
var hash = _.indexBy(array2, 'testProperty');
var result = _.reject(array1, item => _.has(hash, item.testProperty));
```

Comment: thanks for sharing Gruff, it's great to see several different ways to implement the same functionality.